# Get the element that triggers the div onchange

Tags: jquery

Suppose we have the following div:

```
<div id="section">
    <input type="text" id="lastname" />
    <input type="text" id="firstname" />
    <input type="text" id="address" />
</div>
```

And we have the following javascript code:

```
$("#section").on('change', function() {
    //get element that its value changed - code to write here
});
```

If we change the value in one of those input fields the jQuery will fire the change event.

1. Is it possible to get the element that triggers the event on the div?
2. If not, is there any alternative way to identify which element fires the change event without having to write javascript code for each element? Since in a form with many elements that would be inconvenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/okabej/1/edit)**

```
$("#section").on('change', "input", function(event) {
    alert(evt.target.id);
    //get element that its value changed - code to write here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about ***this*** (if you'll pardon the pun)?

```
$("#section").on('change',"input",function(){
    var something = this; //this should refer to your element.
});
```